# Perl installtion on ARMv7eb

Tags: perl, arm

I have cross compiled tool chain for armv7eb. Now I have copied the tools to my target machine and tried to build perl on target. In this process of building perl, there is a binary called 'miniperl' which crashes, outputting "ILLEGAL INSTRUCTION".

Can someone help me point out what I should be doing?

> PERL VERSION: 5.8.8
>   GCC: 4.1.3

Please find the crash log below. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
sh  cflags "optimize='-O'" opmini.o` -DPIC -fPIC -DPERL_EXTERNAL_GLOB opmini.c
          CCCMD =  cc -DPERL_CORE -c -msoft-float -dynamic -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -O  -Wall
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pkg/src/perl-5.8.8:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/pkg/lib:/usr/pkg/src/PTHREAD/lib cc -Wl,-rpath,/usr/pkg/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/pkg/lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib -o miniperl  miniperlmain.o opmini.o -L. -lperl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -lposix
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pkg/src/perl-5.8.8:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/pkg/lpid 25563 (miniperl), uid 0: exited on signal 4 (core not dumped, err = 2)
ib:/usr/pkg/src/PTHREAD/lib ./miniperl -w -Ilib -MExporter -e '<?>' || make minitest
[1]   Illegal instruction     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...
cp ext/re/re.pm lib/re.pm
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pkg/src/perpid 8052 (miniperl), uid 0: exited on signal 4 (core not dumped, err = 2)
l-5.8.8:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/pkg/lib:/usr/pkg/src/PTHREAD/lib ./miniperl -Ilib configpm --heavy=lib/Config_heavy.pl lib/Config.pm
[1]   Illegal instruction     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...
*** Error code 132

Stop.
make: stopped in /upid 25595 (miniperl), uid 0: exited on signal 4 (core not dumped, err = 2)
sr/pkg/src/perl-5.8.8
*** Error code 1 (ignored)

You may see some irrelevant test failures if you have been unable
to build lib/Config.pm, lib/lib.pm or the Unicode data files.

cd t && (rm -f perl; /bin/ln -s ../miniperl perl)  && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pkg/src/perl-5.8.8:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/pkg/lib:/usr/pkg/src/PTHREAD/lib ./perl TEST -minitest base/*.t comp/*.t cmd/*.t run/*.t io/*.t op/*.t uni/*.t </dev/tty
[1]   Illegal instruction     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...
*** Error code 132 (ignored)
*** Error code 1 (ignored)
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pkg/src/perpid 703 (miniperl), uid 0: exited on signal 4 (core not dumped, err = 2)
l-5.8.8:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/pkg/lib:/usr/pkg/src/PTHREAD/lib ./miniperl -Ilib configpm --heavy=lib/Config_heavy.pl lib/Config.pm
```

Comment: is there a reason you're building an ancient version of perl?

Comment: You say you are using `gcc`, but it is calling `cc` which could be something other than `gcc`.

Comment: Try running some basic tests on the toolchain like compiling, linking running a simple C program. Then try adding some of the switches like -fPIC -msoft-float -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -O  -Wall and build/run it again to make sure it still works. If that still works you might try building/running a few other programs to expose toolchain problems. If run into problems you might try running the gcc testsuite to determine the cause.

Comment: I have run a sample program and it is working fine without any issue. I am using gcc only. I have set enviroment for CC as gcc.

Comment: Can you please give me some idea about gcc testsuite? I am not aware of that. any info will help. Thanks